# How to return 1*1 pixel as response from AWS Lambda?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to get 1*1 pixel as response from my **AWS Lambda**.

code is like this  :

```
var imgHex = '47494638396101000100800000dbdfef00000021f90401000000002c00000000010001000002024401003b';
var imgBuffer = new Buffer(imgHex, 'hex');
context.succeed({header:"image/png",data:img});
```

And i mapped response header in **API Gateway**.
But it does't give 1*1 pixel as response.

Comment: Maybe use redirect instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the desired out.

- Instead of converting base64 string to hex, use escaped hexadecimal
  representation of the **1px*1px** image. ie add " **\x** " to each hexadecimal characters.
- AWS Gateway currently not supporting binary data, so it will add
  extra characters to data being send. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38900042/4639822).  So you may not get desired out for every images.
- Here i used image in **bmp** format. And got 1*1 pixel images as
  output.
  Don't forget to set *Content-Type* header in integration response.

  Code:

```js
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    var imageHex = "\x42\x4d\x3c\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x36\x00\x00\x00\x28\x00"+ 
                   "\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x18\x00\x00\x00"+   
                   "\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\x27\x00\x00\x00\x27\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"+
                   "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00";  

    context.succeed({responce:imageHex,header:"image/bmp"});
};
```

**NOTE:**
If you are working with new project and you only want to get hit to your lambda function,one more trick is there. You can give any format of images like png,bmp,gif ect as escaped hexadecimal string. The only problem is that aws gateway modifies your string and sometimes you will get this image
 [image] .
So Just hide your image by using ***display:none*** CSS.

```
<img style="display:none" src ="http://path_to_your_code">
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Integration Response, replace the default application/json content type with image/png and set the mapping template to:

```
#set($result = $input.path('$'))
$result.data
```

Use curl -vvv https://yourendpoint.com/resource to see what headers are returned.

Comment: did this fix work for you?

Comment: i have tried above fix. but i don't get a desired pixel as response.

Comment: what does curl return?

Comment: i got modified output. see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38897368/data-modified-on-aws-api-gateway-response-body/38900042#38900042

Answer (score -2):

API Gateway does not support binary data at the moment. You will have to base64 encode the image before returning it from Lambda, and decode it on the client side. An example is available [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=213508).

Ritisha.

Comment: very informative. but in this case i am not using javascript. so i found a solution in an alternative way. See this http://stackoverflow.com/a/38911642/4639822